# extracting string from pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe, i want to extract number from it, if 'transfer' word is 
    on 8 column it should extract from position 13, 15 character and else it 
    should extract from position 21, 15 character

```
 =IF(LEFT(C10,8)="Transfer",MID(C10,13,15),MID(C10,21,15)) i want same excel from formula in pandas


Particular                                     Expected Result
On-Line Transfer -  01901091900014              01901091900014 
On-Line Transfer -  02501091900004              02501091900004 
On-Line Transfer -  03601091900018              03601091900018 
Transfer -  03631081900095                      03631081900095 
Transfer -  03829081900083                      03829081900083
```

Comment: Try: `df['Expected Result'] = df['Particular'].str.split(' - ').str[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['new_extract_column'] = np.nan

df.loc[ df['column8'].str.contains('transfer'), 'new_extract_column' ] = df[ df['column8'].str.contains('transfer') ].apply(lambda x: x[13:16])

df.loc[ ~df['column8'].str.contains('transfer'), 'new_extract_column' ] = df[ df['column8'].str.contains('transfer') ].apply(lambda x: x[15: 22])
```

Comment: Showing : KeyError: 'column8'

Answer (score 0):

you can use split string method if your data has number at end after space. Else you can use regex

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['On-Line Transfer -  01901091900014'], ['On-Line Transfer -  02501091900004'], ['On-Line Transfer -  03601091900018'], ['Transfer -  03631081900095'], ['Transfer -  03829081900083']], columns=['Particular'])
df["Particular"].str.split().str[-1]
```

Comment: Dear Dev, particulars is having 7,000 lines